# Could a planet be colonized with mostly magic?

Tags: magic, space-travel, space-colonization

How could magic be used to get to planets and make them suitable for human habitation. I will set some rules for the sake of more precise answers.

- Magic and Technology which utilizes it is possible due to magical crystals which channel the user's willpower.
- There is no non-magical technology beyond the 17th century. No spaceships or something similar in particular.
- There are six schools of magic. Evocation gives control over energy, Conjuration gives power over space (not as in Outerspace), Divination gives power over knowledge, Illusion gives power over the mind, Alteration gives control over Inorganic material, and Restoration gives control over organic material.

Comment: What does the word "energy" mean in a 17th century or earlier context? (It [does have a meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiality_and_actuality#Energeia) in that context. That meaning has nothing to do with physics.)

Comment: Given that you don't describe how magic works in your world this question is entirely unanswerable with anything other than the opinions of individual answerers.

Comment: Are you asking about terraforming methods? That depends on what the planet is like, how they get there, the time scale the terraforming project is working on, how large the terraformed area needs to be, and what kind of activity it needs to support (i.e. large scale agricultural societies vs commercial resource extraction vs research station etc). Also, magic can do whatever you want it to.

Comment: VTC as Needs More Detail because this question is unanswerable (or trivially answerable with "sure, it's magic") unless the magic system is better-codified.

Answer (score 3):

You have to decide what limits your magic system has for energy output. You say it channels willpower. How much willpower does a wizard have relative to, say, a 30 pound rock? Can he lift it? Fling it into space like The Hulk? Barely move it at all?

"Magic" pretty well hand waves away all problems. Can you [insert thing here] with [magic system I just now invented]? Uh, sure. Why not. It's your magic system. You can do anything you want with it. But for a more realistic world/story, you'll need to define the limits and how the magic actually works. I don't feel like "willpower" is sufficient to explain turning a mountain into a plain or turning a crater into a lake or causing thousands of acres to have accelerated tree growth. So where is the magic coming from and what are the limits of this power? Can one wizard do it all? How? Does it take multiple wizards a long time? How many and how long?

It's all up to you, but the more precisely you can define it up front, the more consistent you can make the rest of your world.